# Neo4jclient C#: WHERE x IN List

Tags: cypher, neo4jclient

The question is simple. Is it possible to make a WHERE x IN List in Neo4jClient?

Here is an Cypher example:

```
MATCH (tobias { name: 'Tobias' }),(others)
WHERE others.name IN ['Andres', 'Peter'] AND (tobias)<--(others)
RETURN others
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4jclient simply wraps the Cypher REST interface, so yes. Just replace the Cypher keywords with their equivalent methods in IGraphClient and pass whatever you want to .Where (). (I also rewrote your query a little but you can ignore that)

```
var others = graphClient.Cypher
  .Match("({ name: 'Tobias' })<--(others)")
  .Where("others.name IN ['Peter', 'Andres']")
  .Return(others => ...).Results;
```

Replace the three dots with what you want to deserialize to, for example `others.As<IEnumerable<User>>()`.

Comment: Didin't know i could pass a string as an argument of the WHERE. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Here is the same query but using parameters to pass the string[].

.AndWhere("others.Name IN {otherNames}")
.WithParams(new { otherNames })

Check the link for the Github issue raised: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/55